# Spotfire DenseRank + Filters

Tags: graph, expression, visualization, spotfire, dense-rank

I'm trying to make a dynamic top 3 line graph that responds properly to filtering (and maybe marking too). I currently have line by:

```
<If(DenseRank(Sum([Timesheet].[Hours]) OVER ([Timesheet].[Team]),"desc")<=3,[Timesheet].[Team],"Others")>
```

I'd like it to show the top 3 lines for data available after filtering instead of top 3 for the table regardless of filters. As is, it may show no lines at all if the top 3 for the entire table are not part of the filtered data. No matter the filter I'd like to see 3 lines.

Comment: Use show/hide options in the visual to only show the top three values.